# What makes code's border become white?( code is from my hexo blog article ,edited with markdown editor))

Tags: javascript, border, blogs, hexo

I'm writing on my new blog, which was established by hexo ([theme](http://github.com/litten/hexo-theme-yilia)). I used cmd markdown editor, when I previewed blog article by chrome, just found that there was an unexpected white border around my code. Just like this: [white border around my code line, and the border is quadrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM3pX.png) (in the markdown editor, there were 4 or 8 spaces before "my code;"), [look, the border is different from above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhVKR.png)

I'm new to javascript, this is my first question on stackoverflow, I want to konw how to fix it,and why other code is normal. I'm really grateful for your help.

my poor github aticle address: [hellowor1d.github.io/2015/07/11/2015-06-11-JavaScript-function/](http://hellowor1d.github.io/2015/07/11/2015-06-11-JavaScript-function/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following CSS rule:

```
.article-entry p code, .article-entry li code { border: 0; }
```

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer if it has solved your issue.